# Chrome extension can't load Tesseract OCR due to Content Security Policy violation

Tags: content-security-policy

I am building a chrome extension to extract text from image, I use Tesseract do the work. I use npm i tesseract and import to my popup.js. After loading the extension to the browser, while send request to Tesseract, this error occurs

[image]

I tried to download the Tesseract js file and include in my extension's directory, but it seems they are still request from unpkg.com. I use webpack to bundle the files, so it might be that webpack config setup is incorrect, so it doesn't bundle, i do have put tesseract file into webpack.common.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    popup: path.resolve("src/popup/popup.tsx"),
    options: path.resolve("src/options/options.tsx"),
    background: path.resolve("src/background/background.ts"),
    contentScript: path.resolve("src/contentScript/contentScript.ts"),
    tesseract: path.resolve("src/js/tesseract.min.js"),
  },
```

I have this set up in my manifest.js file

```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "../../js/worker.min.js",
        "../../js/tessearct-core.wasm.js",
        "../../traineddata/*.traineddata.gz"
      ],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ]
```

I tried to add this to the manifest.js file

```
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://unpkg.com; object-src 'self'"
  }
```

but then I can't load the extension, error:

> 'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value >"https://unpkg.com" in directive 'script-src'.

Comment: Have you tried adding unpkg.com to script-src of the existing CSP?

Comment: I add this "  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://unpkg.com; object-src 'self'"
  }", but it shows error: 'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value >"https://unpkg.com" in directive 'script-src'.